# Rspec a file which requires others. `require': cannot load such file

Tags: ruby, rspec, require

Is it possible to run an rspec on a file which requires other files?

my .rb file has the following lines:

```
require "colorize"
require "./board_initializer"
require "./pieces"
```

and when running a rake I get the following error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./board_initializer (LoadError)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `require_relative 'board_initializer'` instead.

Comment: Thanks, like that it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means *board_initializer.rb* isn't in the current working directory for *__FILE__*. Some ways to resolve this include:

- Providing a valid filename argument to `require`.
- Using `require_relative` with a valid relative path.
- Modifying the current *LOAD_PATH*.

There are certainly other ways to resolve this, but they all amount to ensuring that *board_initializer.rb* can be found by the interpreter when you load or require the file.

Comment: Thanks, using `require_relative` in the ruby file and nothing in the spec file made the trick.